# Truncate can be rollbacked or not

Tags: sql-server, truncate

I came across multiple articles saying truncate can be rolledback when within a transaction, therefore both truncate and delete can be rolled back. 
1) Rolling back delete command can also be done only when within transaction right ? 
2) When and when we cant roll back a truncate statement

Comment: Yes truncate can be rolled back. There is nothing special or different about it from a transaction perspective

Comment: This is true for SQL Server and the question is for SQL Server. However, for Oracle a truncate cannot be rolled back, so be careful if you target multiple databases!

Answer (score 1):

Any transaction can be rolled back whether it contains TRUNCATE, DELETE or any other operation. The ROLLBACK command only applies to transactions. SQL Server has no feature for "rolling back" any operation that is run outside of a transaction.

To undo operations done outside a transaction you would have to perform a restore from backups.